# Batch file that creates text file, called from another program

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to run a batch file from a different program.

When I run the batch file manually (double clicking the file) it behaves as expected and creates a text file as a result. But when I call the batch file from a program (Winlog SCADA) the text file is not created.

Does anyone know why this happens?

The batch file contains this line of code:

```
systeminfo |findstr /C:"Time Zone" >UTCTime.txt
```

and the code that is calling the batch is (Winlog SCADA):

```
ShellExec(scriptPath,"run",projectPath+"/Settings/",8,".exe","");
```

Comment: +1 Please post the batch file code and the code that is calling the batch file!

Answer (score 0):

The program probably writes to a different folder - try specifying the path to the folder where you want the file.

```
systeminfo |findstr /C:"Time Zone" >"c:\folder\UTCTime.txt"
```